# How to validate DateFormat of specific culture without Time part

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo, tryparse

I need to validate user input on **all culture dates** using TryParse() or TryParseExact() method.

`DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false), DateTimeStyles.None, out date)`

This code validate:

- 01-10-2011
- 1-10-2011
- 01-10-2011 20:11
- 01/10/2011 20:11

But I need it to validate only:

- 01-10-2011
- 1-10-2011

Together with all possible date formats within specified culture:

- 1/10/2011
- 1. oktober 2011

And validation of these should fail:

- 01-10-2011 20:11
- 01/10/2011 20:11

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Where dateString is your date.

Comment: this is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to be able to validate **all possible dates** within some culture e.g. '1.10.2011', '1-10-2011', '1/10/2011', '1. oktober 2011', etc. Your solution will only validate one pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this might help  , you can provide the datetime ( with or without time) as string and wrap it with try catch for validation .

From MSDN - [Convert.ToDateTime Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}{1,-12}{2}\n", "Date String", "Culture", "Result");

      string[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "ru-RU","ja-JP" };
      string[] dateStrings = { "01/02/09", "2009/02/03",  "01/2009/03", 
                               "01/02/2009", "21/02/09", "01/22/09",  
                               "01/02/23" };
      // Iterate each culture name in the array. 
      foreach (string cultureName in cultureNames)
      {
         CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

         // Parse each date using the designated culture. 
         foreach (string dateStr in dateStrings)
         {
            DateTime dateTimeValue;
            try {
               dateTimeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStr, culture);
                // Display the date and time in a fixed format.
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}{1,-12}{2:yyyy-MMM-dd}",
                                  dateStr, cultureName, dateTimeValue);
            }
            catch (FormatException e) { 
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-18}{1,-12}{2}", 
                                  dateStr, cultureName, e.GetType().Name);
            }
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
   }
}
```